# Unable to connect to internet with Azure point to site VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, azure

I setup azure point-to-site vpn. I chose the location as Western Europe, I also used Google's DNS servers in the setup. I created a certificate, uploaded it and then connected to the VPN from my Windows 7 Machine. But I am unable to connect to internet. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: This will be the issue you are seeing: http://superuser.com/questions/662889/cannot-access-internet-or-remote-network-after-connecting-to-windows-vpn

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but Azure's P2S main purpose is to access resources in your Azure subscription (actually in your Azure VNET where you configured the P2S).